# Filter a PCAP file from packet ISO/OSI layer

Tags: python, pcap, scapy, application-layer

I need to split a PCAP file in two different files: the first one should include all (and only) the packets directed to the application layer of the ISO/OSI model, while the second one includes all the other ones.

I'm using Scapy to apply the filter:

```
pkts = PcapReader(infile)
applayerpkts = (pkt for pkt in pkts if pkt.haslayer(Raw))
lowlayerspkts = (pkt for pkt in pkts if not pkt.haslayer(Raw))
wrpcap(applayerfilename, applayerpkts)
wrpcap(lowlayersfilename, lowlayerspkts)
```

using `pkt.haslayer(Raw)` method, since that layer should be included only on packets directed to the application layer.

What's the problem? I've noticed that the sum of `applayerfilename` + `lowlayersfilename` (in file size) is different (lower) from the file size of `infile`.

The reported method is also computationally expensive (and I've got a list of PCAP of ~1.5GB each one), since `infile` is parsed twice.

I'd prefer to apply a different filter, parsing one time the input PCAP.
I could use the `PcapReader` class and manually parsing the PCAP, but I don't know how to generate a PCAP to pass to the `wrpcap(...)` method.

Edit:
I've also tried with this solution:

```
pkts = PcapReader(infile)
app_pkts = []
low_pkts = []
for p in pkts:
    if p.haslayer(Raw):
        app_pkts.append(p)
    else:
        low_pkts.append(p)
wrpcap(applayerfilename, app_pkts)
wrpcap(lowlayersfilename, low_pkts)
```

but it doesn't work, since it consumes too much memory because of the size of my input PCAP...

Does an `append_to_pcap(filename, packet)` like function exists (`wrpcap(...)` function doesn't work as an append)?

Answer (score 0):

I've (at least apparently) solved in this way:

```
pkts = PcapReader(infile)

app_writer = PcapWriter(applayerfilename, append=True)
low_writer = PcapWriter(lowlayersfilename, append=True)
for p in pkts:
    if p.haslayer(Raw):
        app_writer.write(p)
    else:
        low_writer.write(p)
app_writer.close()
low_writer.close()
```